# What is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError ... (Operation Failed: 14)

Tags: java, windows-mobile, mobile, rcp

I am trying to deploy our eRCP (embedded Rich Client Platform) application on a Windows CE5 Professional device. While the eRCP demo applications work fine on the J9 VM upon starting our application I get the following exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2008-09-24 11:01:15.088
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ercp.swt (63).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.ercp.swt.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.ercp.swt.
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: \eRCP\plugins\org.eclipse.ercp.swt.wince5_1.2.0\os\win32\arm\eswt-converged.dll (Operation Failed: 14)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ercp.swt.Activator.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
... 33 more
```

I cannot find anything on the web what "Operation Failed: 14" means. I guess it may be some return value from a native function, but cannot be sure. The DLL *is* present at the location specified and I also tried to put it in the \j9\bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the java exception wraps a native exception from a JNI call, which failed. The DLL probably cannot be loaded or executed correctly on your device for some reason. Wrong OS version? Corrupted DLL file? Not correct read/execution rights? Many possible reasons for it.

edit - seems someone else has a similar problem. SWT bug maybe? See if you can get anything from the developer here:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t111726.html